# =-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, jboss

I am currently trying to start the jbos. The script is below:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11"
set JBossHome=D:\App\jboss-eap-6.3

set Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%
D:
cd %JBossHome%\bin

standalone.bat
```

The issue is that when I run the batch file the following is happened:

```
D:\App\jboss-eap-6.3\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "D:\App\jboss-eap-6.3\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 was unexpected at this time.
```

If anyone have the same problem with me please share.

Thanks and regard.

Comment: Could it be that JBOSSHome missing quotes?

Comment: set JBossHome="D:\App\jboss-eap-6.3". The same problem.

Comment: Go to standalone.conf.bat and search for the string it is complaining and remove it.

Comment: There is no the such string in the standalone.conf.bat file

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into `standalone.conf.bat` for clues. My guess is that there is an environment variable (like `%JAVA_OPTS%`) which contains an illegal value like ending with `...=`. When the script tries to append the options to configure JMX, you get the illegal command line option `=-D...`; there probably has to be a space before the `-D`.

Comment: There was an one space before the -D. I removed it, but the problem is not gone.

Comment: @alexey: There must be a space before the `-D` or Java can't detect the option. I'm wondering why there is a space before the `=`.